# EXCEEDED_ID_LIMIT: Aggregate query does not support queryMore(), use LIMIT to restrict the results to a single batch

Tags: soql, data-loader

When I run following query in dataloader/workbench, I receive the below error.

```
SELECT Count(Id) FROM Account
where recordtype.name = 'Client'
order by COUNT_DISTINCT(Id)
```

> EXCEEDED_ID_LIMIT: Aggregate query does not support queryMore(), use LIMIT to restrict the results to a single batch

How can I work around this issue?

Comment: This is an oft encountered and easily searchable error...That said, I believe you should be able to export a summary report to get the same data.

Comment: Thanks Adrain for quick reply, i searched and got something to apply is offset like SELECT Count(Id), SIC_Code__c FROM Account
where recordtype.name = 'Client'
Group By SIC_Code__c offet 10..but it is returning only 200 records, any idea why it is returning only 200

Comment: dataloader default batch size is 200